# Replacing unknown character with same+changes in notepad++

Tags: notepad++, replace, programmers-notepad

This one is a bit long winded so please bear with me!

I've nailed most of the filtering I need to do with a huge (560,000+ lines) hex capture though I can't fix one problem. I need to filter out lines with multiple timecodes separated by commas... for example

```
00360A,735189.612255,A40A,735189.612255,0000F039003F0D,735189.612255,890763633D
```

The 735189.612255 in this line is the time stamp. The stamp after F0D is required on every line but the others can be removed.

The another annoying part is that the initial part of the timecode is constant (6 digits 735189) the second part changes and is either 3, 4,5 or 6 digits.

I have tried search and replace `[^F0D],735189.......,` which finds the 6 digit ones fine, then reduce the amount of . for 5,4,3 etc and for reference during playing I replaced with the text `DELETE` - Searched for DELETE and removed all instances. Then I discovered that some still remained as they had x0D before the first comma (x being an alphanumeric character that isn't F)

I tried searching for `[^F]0D,735189.....,` etc same as before being replaced with `0DDELETE` only this deletes the x character.

Is there an easier way to do what I'm doing for future reference and how do I replace the [^F] character with the original one when replacing? I could do it manually but that would take hours!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have found one solution which is to search for F0D,735189. and replace with F0D,0735189.

Then searching for ,735189......' returns all of the results that I wish to remove with a further search and replace returning ,0735189. back to ,735189

It's not the best way though it does appear to work. Still open to a solution if anyone has a better one

Comment: This works fine providing that I don't have 735189 elsewhere in the dump which thankfully I don't this time though I might not be so lucky in future